# How to send my server IP to my phone at frequent intervals

Tags: networking

I have a NAS Drive. On the odd occasion, the network goes down, and when it comes back up, the remote IP of the NAS Drive has changed.

I frequently connect to my server from my phone or tablet when I'm out and about, however, I'm unable to connect if the IP changes, and have to wait till I get home to update the IP on my phone.

I have a script on Debian that keeps a log of the remote IP in a text file on my laptop.

Is there a way that I could send that remote IP to my phone at specific intervals (eg. once every half hour), preferably through the use of an automated bash script?

I've looked into a few methods already, but I can't get the following working:

-Textbelt

-Mutt

-ssmtp

-sendmail

Alternative suggestions are welcome. Thanks :)

Comment: Is this all happening inside LAN or you are concerned about your public WAN IP address changes?

Comment: The WAN IP. I figure the easiest way to do it would be to send an email to myself, and it would show up on my phone. But the terminal-based stuff, which would be easiest from my perspective, is a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder why you didn't consider the standard dedicated solution: DNS, which is exactly tailored for the purpose of translating names into IP addresses, and the translation may be dynamic.

Basically, you assign your NAS some public name, and make your script update the that dynamic DNS record with its current IP address. Then you merely access the NAS from the phone using that name and don't even bother with knowing which IP address it is using.

There is a commonly used way to deal with dynamic WAN IP addresses, called [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS). You can use existing providers or make your own (however, the latter is advanced subject and it requires you to have your own public domain delegated to at least two your controlled DNS servers).

Any DNS hoster who provides an API access for programmatic update of records can be used as dynamic DNS provider. If you think it is possible to write a script that sends mails via SMTP, then it is certainly possible to write a script that updates IP using that API.

Start with [Wikipedia list of dynamic DNS providers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Dynamic_DNS) and then you can search for more.

This is much, much more convenient than sending IP via email! Also it enables the valid use of Let's Encrypt to properly secure the service.

Comment: The keyword search is "Dynamic DNS". There are many providers offering exactly this service, many of them for free when it's for just one device

Comment: Yes, I started with that, but it is not clear whether the problem is WAN-related or is it within the LAN, in which case the DDNS provider won't help and you need other means to implement dynamic DNS.

Comment: Agreed. I've assumed "remote IP" meant wan/internet but good point

Comment: Thanks guys. I've used DDNS before, back when I was a kid. 
I just hadn't thought of it in this instance because it's been over a decade since then, and because I was a bit of a tech simpleton back then.

Thankfully the account from back then still works (surprised it's not expired :D), so I've set up and configured that, and got it working.

Thank you for the advice :-)